# audio Ubuntu Problem

Tags: 21.04

I was just recently using ubuntu and tried to fix the audio ic adjustment issue. I them by accidentant turned off all my audio and I  cannot get it to work I tried alsa-force reload, and I've reinstalled the pulseaudio packages. But it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Srry it was version 21.04

Comment: Please clearly write what the problem is, and post the exact commands you had executed. We don't have access to your system, and cannot do anything unless you provide more information. Post the commands between three ``` s so that it would look like `this`. Click here to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1365367/edit) to add more information.